# Fastest/most efficient way to perform this SQL Server 2008 query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains:

-an ID for a financial instrument

-the price

-the date the price was recorded

-the actual time the price was recorded

-the source of the price

I want to get the index ID, the latest price, price source and the date of this latest price, for each instrument, where the source is either "L" or "R". I prefer source "L" to "R", but the latest price is more important (so if the latest price date only has a source of "R"- take this, but if for the latest date we have both, take "L").

This is the SQL I have:

```
SELECT tab1.IndexID, tab1.QuoteDate, tab2.Source, tab2.ActualTime FROM
    (SELECT IndexID, Max(QuoteDate) as QuoteDate FROM PricesTable GROUP BY IndexID) tab1
JOIN
    (SELECT IndexID, Min(Source) AS Source, Max(UpdatedTime) AS ActualTime, QuoteDate FROM PricesTable WHERE Source IN ('L','R') GROUP BY IndexID, QuoteDate) tab2
ON tab1.IndexID = tab2.IndexID AND tab1.QuoteDate = tab2.QuoteDate
```

However, I also want to extract the price field but cannot get this due to the GROUP BY clause. I cannot extract the price without including price in either the GROUP BY, or an aggregate function.

Instead, I have had to join the above SQL code to another piece of SQL which just gets the prices and index IDs and joins on the index ID.

Is there a faster way of performing this query?

EDIT: thanks for the replies so far. Would it be possible to have some advice on which are more efficient in terms of performance?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Why did you also tag this mysql and oracle?

Comment: Because I presumed the syntax was similar-enough for an oracle or mysql developer to help. It's 2008

Comment: No, please don't do that, it's just confusing. If I had a question about my Mercedes I wouldn't also tag it BMW because they're "close enough"...

Comment: I'd try to avoid the `Max(QuoteDate)` because I've seen way to much data written with the exact same date/time down to the fractional second.  I'd use an identity and do MAX() on that identity.  As a result, you can break any "tie" when rows are written at the exact same time, and be sure you have the actual last one and not just one of the ones that has the same max quote date.

Comment: @KM could you give an example- i'm not entirely sure what you mean? Thanks :)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE PricesTable (PriceID int identity(1,1) primary key, your other columns..)` and then: `(SELECT IndexID, Max(PriceID) as MaxPriceID FROM PricesTable GROUP BY IndexID)`  you can join back to PricesTable on the MaxPriceID value to get any other columns you need.

Comment: No real advice on the answers so far - they're so similar that they ought to produce the same execution plans - so it becomes more a matter of which you find more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` within a subquery or CTE to order the rows how you're interested in them, then just select the rows that come at the top of that ordering. (Use `PARITION` so that row numbers are reaassigned starting at 1 for each `IndexId`):

```
;WITH OrderedValues as (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IndexID ORDER BY QuoteDate desc,Source asc) as rn
    FROM
        PricesTable
)
SELECT * from OrderedValues where rn=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select * from
(select p.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by IndexID 
                           order by QuoteDate desc, Source) rn
 from PricesTable p
 where Source IN ('L','R')
) sq
where rn = 1
```

(This syntax should work in relatively recent versions of Oracle, SQLServer or PostgreSQL, but won't work in MySQL.)